# iOS Bluetooth setNotifyValues

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

I have a device that works through Bluetooth, I can connect to it, discover it's services and characteristics (char). However, one of the char is 'repeated' twice, but each with a different property, READ and WRITE. So far so good until I try to subscribe to said char. I get an error. My guess is that, when this is called:

`[peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];`

The first char that's found by the program has the WRITE property, hence it fails.

Is there a way to be more specific with which char to setNotifyValues to, like attaching the property to it?